# She is arrived by the train tomorrow

Tags: passive-voice

Using Present SImple with the movement verbs we can mean the Future:

> 1) She comes by train tomorrow
>
> 2) The steamer sails on Monday
>
> 3) He doesn't return towards here the day after tomorrow

But can we say the same but in the Passive voice:

> 4) She is come by train tomorrow
>
> 5) The steamer is sailed on Monday
>
> 6) He is not returned towards here the day after tomorrow

Comment: The passive voice doesn't make sense for intransitive verbs. It turns the object into the subject and intransitive verbs have no object. Thus, none of the sentences in the second set are equivalent to the one in the first set. Instead, they're equivalent to sentences with transitive verbs: "*Someone* sailed the ship", etc. Since "come" has no transitive variant, sentence (4) is simply wrong. And since the transitive variant of "return" is quite different, sentence (6) has an unintentionally different meaning. In short, avoid passive transformations of intransitive verbs.

Comment: But what about the phrase: "I am gone" or "Gone with the wind"
And it's like a nightmare. I've been always confused with transitive-intransitive verbs.

Comment: That "gone" is an adjective. It's not the same as the past participle in "I have gone". And to take it a step further, "I have been gone" is the perfect tense on "been" plus the adjective "gone", rather than a passive voice. In other words, it's the same as "come" except that there happens to be an adjective "gone" and not an adjective "come" or "came".

Comment: My god, I have been always taking "gone" for V3 from 'go"
You mean we can't use intransitive verbs for the passive voice. It's just such an coincidence that "go" has V3 like "gone" which is identical to the adjective "gone", you mean this?

Comment: Exactly. (The long story is that it's not a coincidence — it's because of the history of the English language. But in Modern English, that's right. They aren't the same "gone".)

Comment: Many past participles can be used as adjectives.

Answer (score 1):

#### The general rule

The key idea of the passive voice is that it takes the **object** of a sentence and makes it the **subject**.

Consider this active voice sentence:

> (a) I             take        the train.
>   
>        <sup>subject      verb           object</sup>

It can become this passive voice sentence:

> (b) The train       is taken      (by me).
>   
>        <sup>subject               verb                complement (optional)</sup>

Notice how "the train" is the object in (a), but it's the subject in (b).

From this observation, you can conclude that the passive voice is impossible if you don't have an object in the original sentence.

---

#### Sentence (4)

It will be helpful to remember that verbs that do not take an object are called "intransitive", and verbs that take an object are called "transitive".

If we look at sentence (1), we see that there is no object:

> She comes by train tomorrow.

This is not surprising since "come" is always an intransitive verb. You can't "come something". Therefore, something can't "be come" or "be came".

So (4) is impossible.

---

#### Sentences (5) and (6)

Now, looking at (2) and (3), you'll see that they have no object either. So you would conclude that (5) and (6) are impossible.

However, there's one more point to consider. Many verbs have both a transitive and an intransitive version. These two versions often mean different things. For example, you can "jog" (do an exercise), or you can "jog someone's memory" (remind them of something).

This is true of "sail" and "return". So sentences (5) and (6) are not impossible.

Further, "sail" means basically the same thing in both its transitive and intransitive versions. Therefore, (5) is a pretty good sentence. It means basically the same thing as (2).

However, "return" does not mean the same thing in both versions. The intransitive version means "*come* back", but the transitive version means "*give* back". It sounds odd to "give someone back", and it's different from the person coming back on their own. Therefore, (6) is not good. It doesn't mean the same thing as (3).

Comment: 1) How should I distinguish "object" and "complement" in a sentence?
2) "Therefore, (5) is a pretty good sentence. It means basically the same thing as (2)." What can it mean in a not basical case?
3) So, "6) He is not returned towards here the day after tomorrow" is grammatically correct but has a different meaning, right?

Comment: 4) If I say "The ship sails tomorrow". It means some action which will happen in the future due to some timetable. If I will say it in Passive - "The ship is sailed tomorrow" it will be completely correct? This is what I wanted to know, if we could use Passive voice for the timetable usage cases as we did for the Active Voice. Just I gave some wrong examples with trnasitive-intransitive voice and we changed the topic a little bit.

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko **(1)** "complement" is broader. You can regard most prepositional phrases attached to verbs as complements (e.g. of time, place, instrument) but not objects, i.e. they are not required parts of the verb's structure. **(2)** There's a very subtle difference in emphasis. It's another whole topic but in short: if we think of the passive voice as allowing us to hide a verb's subject, then certain intransitive verbs like "sail" do so with an even stronger effect. It takes the action of sailing and treats the inanimate ship as if it were responsible!

Comment: **(3)** Yes, except that, as I mentioned, you should delete "towards". That part is completely unnatural. **(4)** Hmm, you have actually noticed something which is indeed a more interesting question. I think there is something odd there. The passive voice makes it hard to read the present tense as referring to the future. This is just an intuition, and I would be interested to hear what other people think.

Comment: 1) "You can regard most prepositional phrases attached to verbs as complements (e.g. of time, place, instrument) but not objects, i.e. they are not required parts of the verb's structure." Can you please bring some examples for this explanation for the better understanding of mine?
2) Is "sail" intransitive?
You mean if I say "We sail the steamer" in Passive - "The stemar is sailed by us" and hide this sentence's subject making "The steamer is sailed", then the sentence becomes even stronger or what? And I didn't understand about "responsbile". What becomes responsible here?

Comment: My favorite moment:
"He is not returned towards here". 
1) If you go to the casino, spend your money and start complaning, people will say "Money is not returned here" like "within here".
2) If you win some money and go away people will say that "money is not returned to here" like "towards here".
Or in different words: to return something here you should be here yourself, you should be within here, on this very territory to return something here. If you're not within this territory, you're not within here, then you return something to\towards here. No? How should I distinguish them then?

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko "He is not returned towards here" is not English, for your information. If a person is dead, you could say in a movie script: He [as in a dead body] is not returned to the house, he is returned to the morgue. [in other words] Or We are returning him to the morgue.